# Angular Material: Best way to update datasource on edit?

Tags: javascript, angular-material, datasource

Can someone tell me the best way to update my `mat-table` (with a `DataSource`) when a row is edited? I'd like for the page to not have to refresh, thereby losing the currently selected row and any sorting.

My edit table is in a dialog box. Just don't know what to do when I get back to the table...

This is the table html:

```
    <mat-table id="mainTable" #table [dataSource]="dataSourceA" matSort>

      <ng-container matColumnDef="selection">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>
          <mat-checkbox (change)="$event ? masterToggle() : null" [checked]="selection.hasValue() && isAllSelected()"
            [indeterminate]="selection.hasValue() && !isAllSelected()">
          </mat-checkbox>
        </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">
          <mat-checkbox (click)="$event.stopPropagation()" (change)="$event ? selection.toggle(row) : null"
            [checked]="selection.isSelected(row)">
          </mat-checkbox>
        </td>
      </ng-container>

      <ng-container matColumnDef="commonName">
        <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>Common Name</mat-header-cell>
        <mat-cell *matCellDef="let certdata">{{certdata.commonName}}</mat-cell>
      </ng-container>

      <ng-container matColumnDef="owner">
        <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>Owner</mat-header-cell>
        <mat-cell *matCellDef="let certdata">{{certdata.owner}}</mat-cell>
      </ng-container>

      <ng-container matColumnDef="expirationDate">
        <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>Expiration Date</mat-header-cell>
        <mat-cell *matCellDef="let certdata">{{certdata.expirationDate | date}}</mat-cell>
      </ng-container>

      <ng-container matColumnDef="environment">
        <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>Environment</mat-header-cell>
        <mat-cell *matCellDef="let certdata">{{certdata.environment}}</mat-cell>
      </ng-container>

      <ng-container matColumnDef="edit">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef class="mat-column-edit"></th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">
          <button mat-raised-button (click)="openEditDialog(row)">Edit</button>
        </td>
      </ng-container>

      <mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumnsA"></mat-header-row>
      <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumnsA;" matRipple class="element-row" [cdkDetailRow]="row"
        [cdkDetailRowTpl]="tpl"></mat-row>
    </mat-table>
```

This is my component code:

```
openEditDialog(data) {
    const editDialogConfig = new MatDialogConfig();

    editDialogConfig.disableClose = true;
    editDialogConfig.autoFocus = true;
    editDialogConfig.width = "900px";

    editDialogConfig.data = data;

    const dialogRef = this.editDialog.open(EditDialogComponent, editDialogConfig);

    dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(result => {
      console.log("dialog closed");
      this.dialogData = result;
      console.log(this.dialogData);

      let headers = new HttpHeaders({
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + this.authService.getToken()
      });
      let options = { headers: headers };

      this.http.post<CertData>(`http://localhost:8102/certtracker/certs/update`, this.dialogData, options)
        .subscribe(response => {
          console.log(response);
        });
    })
  }
}
```

Comment: Does ` this.http.post<CertData>` give you the table data?

Comment: Yes, that's the idea. I don't know if I need to retrieve the whole table again or not. I just want one row to update.

Comment: you don't have the `dataSourceA` in your `.ts` though. Is this the full code?

Comment: I tried to only include what I thought was pertinent. The whole TS is kinda big...

Answer (score 0):

Ok I couldn't understand your question, but if you mean avoid to refresh the page when you update the datasource and you want to show the new rows, edit, etc.. I implemented a Database class:

```
export class DatabaseName {
  dataChange: BehaviorSubject<YourModel[]> = new BehaviorSubject<YourModel[]>([]);

  get data(): YourModel[] {
    return this.dataChange.value;
  }

  set data(value: YourModel[]) {
    this.dataChange.next(value);
  }

  constructor() { }

  addShareholder(shareholder: YourModel) {
    const copiedData = this.data.slice();
    copiedData.push(shareholder);
    this.dataChange.next(copiedData);
  }

  editShareholder(shareholder: YourModel, index: number) {
    const copiedData = this.data.slice();
    copiedData.splice(index, 1, shareholder);
    this.dataChange.next(copiedData);
  }

  deleteShareholder(index: number) {
    const copiedData = this.data.slice();
    copiedData.splice(index, 1);
    this.dataChange.next(copiedData);
  }
}

export class DataSourceName extends DataSource<YourModel> {

  constructor(private DBname: DatabaseName) {
    super();
  }


  connect(): Observable<YourModel[]> {
    return this.DBname.dataChange;
  }

  disconnect() { }
}
```

You must use a BehaviorSubject, I saw this holy code from a example 5 months ago

this is the entire example, this saved my life: https://github.com/marinantonio/angular-mat-table-crud

Comment: Thanks, you have the idea of what I'm trying to do, but I don't understand how to implement your answer.

Comment: I feel you, its complicating but I tried all. You must use it below your parent code and when you need to edit for example: `dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(result => {
      //console.log('Closing...')
      if (!this.backDropClicked) {
        if(result){
          this.database.editShareholder(result, index);
        }
      }
      this.backDropClicked = false;
    });`

Comment: its very easy, just instance the database class in the parent.
I gave you a complete example, its a very good example

Comment: Ok, I'm trying to implement your example. Where does `backDropClicked` go though? Where should it be defined and referenced?

Comment: I used it like a boolean flag. If the user click on backdrop or press ESC I changed to true, but its my case.. something like this

`dialogRef.backdropClick().subscribe((e) => {
      this.backDropClicked = true;
      dialogRef.close();
    });`

`dialogRef.keydownEvents().subscribe((e) => { 
      if (e.key === 'Escape') {
        this.backDropClicked = true;
        dialogRef.close();
      }
    })
`